# looking to seal cedar playset

Tags: staining

I just bought some really nice cedar wood that I am building a swingset with. I have kept the wood indoors because I am wanting to seal it to further protect it from the weather ... but I really want to keep the beauty of the wood itself. The color and grain if you will.

I am confused on what products to use ... I hear of people staining it and then sealing it with poly ... some people talk about using marine products, etc etc.

I heard good reviews of a product called 'McCloskey Man O’War Spar Marine Varnish' ... but it doesnt look like it has UV protection. Can anyone give me any info and/or products that I should use?